# React setter warning: Functions are not valid as a React Child

Tags: reactjs, typescript, remix

This is my first React project, so thank you in advance for bearing with me if this is a basic question. I have a two range inputs and I am trying to perform a calculation and update content when those range inputs are moved. Here's my file:

index.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react'

export default function Index() {

  let hours = React.useState(2)
  const setHours = (newHours) => {
    hours = newHours;
    setPrice(hours, price);
  }

  let miles = React.useState(18)
  const setMiles = (newMiles) => {
    miles = newMiles;
    setPrice(hours, price);
  }

  let price = React.useState(0)
  const setPrice = (hours, miles) => {
    price = hours * 6.00 + miles * 0.32
  }
  setPrice(hours, miles);


  return (
    <div>
       <p className="font-medium">Estimated fee of ${price} for a {hours} hour, {miles} mile trip.</p>
       <input onChange={(e) => setHours(e.target.value)} value={hours} type="range" min="1" max="24" />
        <input onChange={(e) => setMiles(e.target.value)} value={miles} type="range" min="1" max="200" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

This unfortunately throws a warning "Functions are not valid as a React child."

Comment: Which version of react your using that's not the way you create state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's not how you should use the useState hook in case you want the value you should use the following:

`const [hours, setHours] = useState()`

then you can use hours as you used it in the example above now you're giving a `useState()` hook as the value of your input and that would definitely cause the error you have.
please follow [this link](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) to see more about `useState` hook

Comment: How do I then edit setHours to call my setPrice function?

Comment: then your `setHours` would be `hoursHandler` and inside of that `hoursHandler` you can use the `setHours` I have in the answer to set the value of your new hours and using the same logic you would call the `setPrice` to set your new price...

Comment: But I highly recomand a tutorial to help you understanding the ReactJS lifecycle because it isn't that clear to use at the frist place...

Comment: Thank you, this set me on the right direction. I am currently doing a tutorial alongside this project, but I went down a rabbit hole here and got a bit ahead of what I've learned in the tutorial. I'll post the final complete solution.

Comment: Perfect! good luck in your journey with ReactJS

Answer (score 1):

```
  const [hours, setHours] = React.useState(2)
  const [miles, setMiles] = React.useState(18)
  const [price, setPrice] = React.useState(0)

  const handleHours = (newHours) => {
    setHours(newHours)
    handlePrice()
  }

  const handleMiles = (newMiles) => {
    setMiles(newMiles)
    handlePrice()
  }

  const handlePrice = () => {
    let newPrice = hours * 6.00 + miles * 0.32;
    setPrice(newPrice)
  }
```